# How to know next state in ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm showing and hiding a modal when the user go to a specific state (`/login`), but I would keep the modal in background if the users goes to `/register` from `/login`.

If the user is in `/login` and then goes to `/register`, I would the login modal to stay opened, while if the user is in `/login` and then goes to a different page, I would the login modal to disappear.

Actually I set the `Angular-ui-router` `$stateProvider` in this way:

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: "/",
      templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
      controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    })
    .state('login', {
      url: "/login",
      onEnter: function ($stateParams, $state, Modal) {
        // * modalCtrl for Login
        if (window.loginModal) {
          window.loginModal.remove();
          delete window.loginModal;
          Modal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/user/login.html', function (modal) {
            window.loginModal = modal;
            loginModal.show();
          });
        } else {
          Modal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/user/login.html', function (modal) {
            window.loginModal = modal;
            loginModal.show();
          });
        }
      },
      onExit: function ($stateParams, $state) {
        if ( window.loginModal && /* condition like "!nextState.is('register')" */ ) {
          window.loginModal.hide();
        }
      }
    })
    .state('register', {
      url: "/register",
      onEnter: function ($stateParams, $state, Modal, SlideBoxDelegate) {
        // * modalCtrl for Register
        if (window.registerModal) {
          window.registerModal.remove();
          delete window.registerModal;
          Modal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/user/register.html', function (modal) {
            window.registerModal = modal;
            SlideBoxDelegate.update();
            registerModal.show();
          });
        } else {
          Modal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/user/register.html', function (modal) {
            window.registerModal = modal;
            SlideBoxDelegate.update();
            registerModal.show();
          });
        }
      },
      onExit: function ($stateParams, $state) {
        if ( window.registerModal ) {
          window.registerModal.hide();
        }
      }
    })
    .state('not_found', {
      url: "/not_found",
      templateUrl: 'templates/not_found.html',
      controller: 'NotFoundCtrl'
    })
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/not_found");
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
})
```

Is there a way to set the `condition like "!nextState.is('register')"`?

Thank you for reading :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen for `$stateChangeStart` and note the value of the `to` parameter some place that is accessible to your `onExit` function, i.e. an injectable value or service.

In the future, there will be an injectable service that will represent the transition itself, which you'll be able to inspect and manipulate for things like this.

Comment: Any word on this service?

Comment: It would be nice if `onExit` callback had *toState* and *toParams* just like `$stateChangeStart` have. Same applies to `onEnter`

Answer (score 2):

The best trick I have found so far is to use the promise inside the $state service, in the `onExit` function :

```
onExit: function ($state) {
  $state.transition.then(toState => {
    if (toState.name === 'nameOfTheWantedNextState') {
      $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});
    }
  })
}
```

This avoids listening to the event and storing the name somewhere, it only uses whats available at the time of the transition. Quite neat !